# Wheel issue with BigARTM

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I am trying to install BigARTM on Ubuntu following the [instruction](http://bigartm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/linux.html).

Everything goes fine until I run `sudo make`.

It generates the following error:

```
[ 99%] Building python package bigartm
running build
running build_py
[ 99%] Built target python_bigartm_build
[100%] Building wheel bigartm
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
python/CMakeFiles/python_bigartm_wheel.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'python/CMakeFiles/python_bigartm_wheel' failed
make[2]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/python_bigartm_wheel] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:781: recipe for target 'python/CMakeFiles/python_bigartm_wheel.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/python_bigartm_wheel.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

I suspected that the problem is connected with wheel. So I updated wheel:

```
user@user:~/bigartm/build$ pip install wheel
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.31.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.31.0
```

Also I updated wheel in conda, and it shows now:

```
$ conda list | grep wheel

wheel                     0.31.0                   py36_0  
wheel                     0.31.0                    <pip>
```

That did not help.

Comment: It seems related more to setuptools (or even distutils) than wheel. What's the output of `pip freeze | grep setuptools`?

Comment: Nothing, but installing it doesn't help:

Comment: sooobus@sooobus-HP-ENVY:~$ pip install setuptools --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
sooobus@sooobus-HP-ENVY:~$ pip freeze | grep setuptools

Comment: Install/update wheel using conda, not pip. I guess that "pip" command refers to something outside your conda env. However, your "conda list" suggests that wheel is already up to date :-/

Comment: I tried also to do it using conda and pip is inside conda: `$ which pip
/home/sooobus/anaconda3/bin/pip`

Comment: Could also be related to the fact that you're using "sudo make". What about "make" in your conda env? I think that "sudo make" lead Python to use binaries outside of your (virtual) environment.

Comment: Excluding sudo doesn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

seems like you don't have some library called `bdist_wheel`. it is imported by `setuptools`.

```
pip install setuptools
```

Also you need to install some following libraries (just `pip install XXX` where `XXX` is name of the library that errors).

[Edit]

You can't install BigARTM now.